# How do I convert an unsigned to uint64_t?

Tags: c, c99, unsigned

I've got an `unsigned` and would like to convert that to an `uint64_t` (and back if possible).

How do I do that? If possible, I would like to avoid depending on undefined behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance:

```
const uint64_t bigvalue = (uint64_t) 42u;
```

Not sure if the cast is even necessary, since this doesn't loose information. The opposite:

```
const unsigned int smallvalue = (unsigned int) bigvalue;
```

will need the cast, since it's (probably, assuming `int` < `uint64_t`) a more narrow type.

Note: I mean "need" in a weak sense; since there is a risk of losing information when converting to a more narrow type, it's likely that compilers will warn. The cast adds a sense of "I know what I'm doing" which is how such warnings are typically silenced.

Comment: no cast is needed, never, conversion between unsigned types is always well defined

Answer (score 6):

The conversion to unsigned integer types from any integer types is completely defined by the standard (section 6.3.1.3, paragraph 2). If the value can be represented in the target type, it is preserved, otherwise the value is reduced modulo `2^WIDTH`, where `WIDTH` is the width (number of value bits) of the target type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with typecasting:

`uint64_t new = (uint64_t) old;`

Where `old` is your unsigned int.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're in C land, a cast will be your only way. Simply do

```
uint64_t foo = (uint64_t)myVar;
```

Or, in reverse

```
unsigned int bar = (unsigned int)foo;
```

Your compiler should pick up the conversion automatically though, although in the case of a `uint64_t` -> `unsigned int`, you should get a warning regarding truncation. Also, the value will of course be truncated when converting back, unless you are compiling in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: cast should never be needed here, and generally are to be avoid wherever possible

Comment: @JensGustedt - I'd assumed the OP had tried that, hence suggesting the cast, and my final paragraph. It is a good point though, you shouldn't cast unless you really, _really_ need to.